# SpringFramework controller test NoInitialContextException JAVA

Tags: java, spring

I have this NoInitialContextException exception. Hope someone will help me to fix it.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passportDataSource' defined in class path resource [bg/abv/profiles/controller/integration/test/datasources.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework uses JNDI API. Since it's just an API, rather than an implementation, you need to tell it which implementation of JNDI to use. You can use Spring's [JNDITemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiTemplate.html) and pass the required parameters via a properties file including `java.naming.factory.initial` which is what this error trace is highlighting

You can achieve that like the following example which uses annotation based Spring configuration.

```
@Bean
 DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
     JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
     try {
           dataSource = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/jndiName");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for java:comp/env/jdbc/jndiName", e);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand anything. Please show me how to fix it.

Comment: I use xml configuration. How to write it in xml ?